# Facebook graph api multiple keyword search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api to search the keywords, like as follows

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='test'&limit=60&access_token=(myAccessToken)
```

Which works fine and returns the data correctly.

But I want to search with multiple keywords (Eg . I need the post which contains the words 'test' or 'date')

I tried in the following way, which is working but returns the array which contains the words test and date. It doesn't return the results of individual words.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=test|date&limit=60&access_token=
                                                           (myAccessToken)
```

Is it possible to implement graph api search with multiple keywords in "OR" condition?
If so explain how?

Answer (score 2):

I know that is one year later but did you manage to find a solution? I've tried with different methods, like putting " | " character, but nothing works. I'm wondering to give it a try to [batch request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests), passing on each query each keyword that I'm interested in and loop later through the responses to filter repeated results.

Answer (score -3):

You can use FQL. For example if you have two different artists pages and you want to get information about both:

```php
$fql = 'SELECT name,fan_count,page_id,hometown,record_label from page WHERE name="Rihanna" OR name="Jay z" LIMIT 2';
$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => $fql));

    foreach( $ret_obj as $var)
    {
        var_dump($var);
    }
```

This code will return you an array that has the required information about both artists.